# Why is my position:absolute not obeying my position:relative div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Could anyone explain to me please why my position:absolute div is not obeying my position:relative div?

I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't for the life of me see what it is.

I would like to see the position:absolute div (class-2) positioned inside of the position:relative div (class-1).

These are the two class', full link to code below:

```
div.class-1 {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.class-2 {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#C96;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">class-before</div>
    <div class="class-1">class-1</div>
    <div class="class-2">class-2</div>
    <div class="after">class-after</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craig_wadman/HMwtN/

Hope that all makes sense?

Answer (score 5):

The absolute positioned element must be nested inside the relative positioned element for the desired result:

```
<div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-2">class-2</div>
</div>
```

Absolute positioning 101: an absolute positioned element is positioned with respect to the closest positioned (relative, absolute or fixed) parent; if there is none then `<body>` is used (that was the case with your original markup).

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/HMwtN/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Its not inside it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">class-before</div>
    <div class="class-1">class-1
        <div class="class-2">class-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="after">class-after</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/HMwtN/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your class-2 is not within the class-1. Place the  after class-2.

```
 <div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-2">class-2</div>
</div>
```